# How to change the User Relationship tab path

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules, relationships

I use the module [User Relationships](http://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) in Drupal 7 and it generated a nice tab in on the User Profile. I use a specific type of relationship "friends" so I need both the tab as the path to reflect this. I already user the module [Tab Tamer](http://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) to overwrite the tab name, I just cannot seem to find where the path is set. I would imagine seeing a view in the Views UI or to find it in the module dir itself, but so far no luck.

In short, is there a way to change **users/%/relationships** into **users/%/friends**?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use a custom module to create a new menu tab with exactly the link you want, and remove the default tab. [This](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/how-to-add-additional-tabs-to-user-profiles) provides an example.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion and link, I however do know how to create a tab, but as the User Relationship module generates their view (and thus tab) in the module itself, and is not visible in the Views UI, I would need to disable the module. This is not something I would like to do, and more interested in how this would be possible within the context of the module itself.